# como pasar una propiedad de una instancia como parámetro a una función en python?

Tags: python, funciones, objeto

quisiera saber cual es la forma o bien, la sintaxis para poder hacer una función que pasandole un parametro se pueda acceder a la propiedad de una instancia.

por ejemplo, si tengo la **clase Car** y cada instancia tendrá **ruedas,marca y año** como podría acceder a esas propiedades desde una función?

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self,ruedas,marca,año):
        self.ruedas = ruedas
        self.marca = marca
        self.año = año

carrito = Car(4,'toyota',2015)
```

y si ahora hago

```
carrito.marca # 'toyota' por supuesto
#pero
carrito["marca"] #TypeError: 'Car' object is not subscriptable
```

y lo que yo quisiera hacer es algo como

```
def segunPropiedad(instancia,propiedad):
    #posible manera 1) nota:en JavaScript funciona de esta manera pero en python no
    valor = instancia[propiedad]
    # o bien posible manera 2
    valor = instancia.propiedad
    return valor

segunPropiedad(carrito,ruedas)
# o bien
segunPropiedad(carrito,"ruedas")
```

lo intento por 2 maneras, con **instancia.propiedad** y con **instancia[propiedad]**,pero siempre me da estos errores TypeError: 'Car' object is not subscriptable y NameError: name 'ruedas' is not defined
el 2do error lo entiendo porque ruedas no está definido ok, pero que significa is not subscriptable?

hago ésta pregunta ya que tengo un codigo en python que lo estoy repitiendo mucho y solo es una pequeña parte lo que varía, la parte de obtener el valor por medio de la propiedad.
La manera # 2 osea, instancia[propiedad] me sirvió en Javascript pero en python pensé que seria igual pero no funcionó. Y como vengo de Javascript me es muy familiar un diccionario y una instancia de un objeto pero al parecer se manejan diferentes por ejemplo

```
#si carrito fuera un diccionario
carrito = {"marca": 'mazda', "año": 2016}
carrito["marca"]# 'mazda' claro
carrito.marca # error

# pero si carrito fuese una instancia
#la cosa es al revés
carrito.marca# mazda
carrito["marca"] # error
```

**en fin,** para resumir la pregunta: como podría hacer que la función **segunPropiedad()** de ejemplo que coloqué más arriba funcionase? 
bueno, si me pueden ayudar les doy gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python ofrece una función llamada `getattr()`. Si revisas la documentación puedes ver que recibe como parámetros el objeto y el atributo que quieres obtener de ese objeto.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr

Entonces en lugar de tu función

```
segunPropiedad(carrito, "ruedas")
```

puedes hacer:

```
getattr(carrito, 'ruedas')
```

O si quieres encapsularlo y hacer otras cosas al obtener el atributo (por ejemplo manejar errores)

```
def segunPropiedad(instancia,propiedad):
    return getattr(instancia, propiedad)

segunPropiedad(carrito, 'ruedas')
```

Ojo, debes implementar una forma de acceder a los atributos de forma segura, ya que si intentas acceder a un atributo que no existe, python tirará una excepción **`AttributeError`**